# Can I use "and" more than once in this case?

Tags: grammar, sentence

> Take a selfie that changes with your feelings based on your biometric input and social media and other real-time data in you region.

"Social media" and "real-time data" is apart of your region-- "biometric input" is not.

The alternative is,

> Take a selfie that changes with your feelings based on your biometric input, social media trends and other real-time data in you region.

But I feel like this way it reads as social media trends isn't apart of "in your region". Am I wrong?

Comment: I do not understand this at all - it seems to make no sense whatever to me. There may, however be a valid question at the heart of it. Could the problem be posed with a more simple sentence, beginning let's say, *The cat sat on the mat...based on...and...and...*?

Comment: Please be more careful in wording your questions.  Why does *trends* appear in the alternative version, but not the first?  I'm sure you mean *your region", not "you region."  And likely you want "a part" instead of "apart".  Even so, what does "a part" mean for the syntax of your sentences?  I've guessed in an answer below, but it's only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Using "and" more than once in the same list sounds awkward. Use the commas.

That's not to say that you can't use "and" more than once in the same sentence, as long as it's joining different "kinds of things". Like, "I gave the green box to Bob and Sally, the red box to Fred, and the yellow box to Janet." I use "and" to join Bob with Sally and also to join what I did with the three boxes, but it's in different contexts, so that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is badly worded.  (See my comment.) But if I interpret "apart" to mean "a part", I think you're asking whether *other* refers (properly) to *social media trends* or whether it also refers (improperly) to biometric input.  If it's the latter, then *in your region* would falsely imply that biometric data is real-time data associated with the region.

The answer is that syntax can take you only so far, and if I'm correct in my assumptions above, your sentence is syntactically ambiguous.  The commas won't help since they do nothing but emphasize the syntax of a list.  At some point, you're allowed to assume that your audience understands the semantics of what you write, so they'll know that biometric data is associated with a person, not a region, especially if you've explained previously that biometric data isn't collected in real time.

If you're still concerned, then the solution is to reword:

> Take a selfie that changes with your feelings based on your biometric
>   inputs and your region's real-time data such as social media
>   trends.

Answer (score 0):

I like to alter the structure to make it obvious what each *and* governs:

> Take a selfie that changes with your feelings based on your biometric input and *on* social media and other real-time data in your region.

Now the first *and* can only govern the two prepositional phrases, "on your biometric input" and "on social media and etc."

Comment: Did you intend to italicise an _and_?

Comment: Yes, I meant it to mean "the word 'and'".  In the quotation, I italicized the added word.

Comment: Ah. More usual to use square brackets. I was thinking 'Take a selfie that changes with your feelings based on your biometric input _and_ [on] social media and other real-time data in your region.' This emphasises the first 'and', the second being almost 'schwaed', bringing out the different coordination levels.

Answer (score 0):

*Take a selfie that changes with your feelings based on your biometric input and social media and other real-time data in your region.*

Since social media and other real-time data are a part of your region, you would would replace the "and" after biometric data with a comma.
*Take a selfie that changes with your feelings based on your biometric input, social media and other real-time data in your region.*

If social media and other real-time data were not a part of your region, you would add a comma after social media, denoting the three terms are separate. This comma is known as an Oxford Comma. *Take a selfie that changes with your feelings based on your biometric input, social media, and other real-time data in your region.*

Answer (score 0):

In a word...No!

Usage of 'and' more than once in a sentence is poor English.
Correct usage is to use commas between the examples (if more than two), with the last example joined with the use of 'and'.

i.e. '... on your bio-metric input, social media and other real-time data...'

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, social media is not real time  data.
Therefore it is perfectly acceptable to include 'social media' in this list.
So long as it is accepted that 'other real time data' does not refer to either of the previously stated examples used in the list.